# Creating a Bidirectional Hashtable constructor

Tags: java, generics, hash, constructor, hashtable

i have an assigment in which i am suposed to create a bidirectional hashtable.
I am suposed to make a constructor for the bidirectionalHashTable,  but i am completly clueless on how to make one, since i usually dont use one.
Can anyone give me a tip on what i am suposed to do? like i am suposed to use the constructor to store all the possible operations that i can do with the hashTable?

Here is the code :

```
public class BidirectionalHashtable<K, V> {

/**
 * construtor
 */
public BidirectionalHashtable() {
}

/**
 * returns a value, gets the corresponding key
 * @param value - the value
 * @return K - the key
 */
public K getKey(V value) {
    return null;
}

/**
 * receives a key, gets the corresponding value
 * @param key - key
 * @return V - value
 */
public V getValue(K key) {
    return null;
}
```

and some more methods like put(), containsValue(), etc etc

Answer (score 0):

My advice? Delete the constructor. A constructor sets state (fields) of the object as may be required for correct functionality. Often, there is nothing special required - fields requiring initialization can be given values as part of their declaration, eg:

```
private String prefix = ""; // declare an initial value
private String name; // if not initialized, it's null
```

If you have code you must run in the constructor declare one.
If you don't need any such code, don't define (an empty) one.